# How to send a large data response in a node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am getting this error if I send whole data-
: JSON.stringify(value);
^

RangeError: Invalid string length
at JSON.stringify ()

and works fine if I send small data.

Answer (score 0):

Hi yes it's actually a known issue, you can cut your value into pieces and then apply the method if you really need to.
You can refer to this : https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/35973
Just quoting some interesting solutions
From: paulsmithkc

> Consider processing the JSON chunk, by chunk as it comes in, rather than trying to load it all into a string and then parsing it.
>
> This will drastically lower the amount of memory needed, and speed up
> the overall file load time.